# Неуказанная область видимости

Tags: php

Какая область видимости считается неуказанной и где она может встречаться?
В документации по этой [ссылке](http://php.net/manual/ru/closure.bindto.php) написано следующее

> Для нестатического замыкания с незаданной областью видимости, но с
>   указанием объекта, создается замыкание с неуказанной областью
>   видимости.

***Если нужен код то вот:***

```
class A
{
     private $text = "hello";
} 
$a = new A; 
$closure = function(){echo $this->text;};
$binding = $closure->bindTo($a); 
/// Тут мы не указали в каком контексте будет выполнятся
///анонимная функция, соответственно тут неуказанная область видимости то есть 
///`static`. А что есть такое static в данном контексте?
///P.S Если мы укажем область видимости как "A", то никакой ошибки не будет
$binding(); /// Тут ошибка доступа
```

Comment: Нет такого понятия "неуказанная область видимости" :)

Comment: @TimurMusharapov ну вот в документации так написано, хотя я сам вижу такую запись впервые

Comment: @MaximPro, можно ссылку?

Comment: @TimurMusharapov ссылка в вопросе написана

Comment: Товарищи что поставили минусы и не могут ответить на мой вопрос, что вы хотите чтобы я указал? Что я написал в вопросе такое что вам непонятно? Я хочу разобраться в сути вопроса, а вы просто молча минус, так нельзя!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class A{
    private function getTest(){
        return 'Private';
    }
}


$closure = function(){
    echo $this->getTest();
};

$class = new A();


$fun = $closure->bindTo($class, 'A');
$fun();
$fun = $closure->bindTo($class);
$fun();
```

Класс передаётся во второй параметр и действительно если не передать во второй параметр ничего  или null то метод будет вызван статически `A::getTest()`

> newthis Объект, к которому будет привязана переданная функция, или
>   NULL для отсоединения функции от ее текущего объекта.
>
> newscope Область
>   видимости класса, с которой ассоциируется замыкание, или 'static' для
>   сохранения текущей области видимости. Если передан объект, то будет
>   использован его класс. Этот параметр определяет видимость protected
>   (защищенных) и private (закрытых) методов привязанного объекта.

`public Closure Closure::bindTo ( object $newthis [, mixed $newscope = "static" ] )`
И далее

> Для нестатического замыкания с незаданной областью видимости, но с
>   указанием объекта, создается замыкание с неуказанной областью
>   видимости.
>   А точнее
>
> Для нестатического замыкания, с указанной областью видимости и с NULL
>   вместо объекта, будет создано статическое замыкание. Для
>   нестатического замыкания с незаданной областью видимости, но с
>   указанием объекта, создается замыкание с неуказанной областью
>   видимости.

т.е. если $newthis=null и $newscope = private | protected | public то это будет статичная функция т.е. $newthis=null и $newscope=static

Comment: Я привёл примеры описывающие документацию

Comment: Можете написать один рабочий пример со вторым аргументом где вы укажите "private", тогда я про бред заберу свои слова обратно
Лично я не видел чтобы в качестве второго аргумента указывалась область видимости через ключевые слова `private | protected | public`

Comment: @MaximPro Область видимости класса, с которой ассоциируется замыкание, или 'static' для сохранения текущей области видимости. Если передан объект, то будет использован его класс. Этот параметр определяет видимость protected (защищенных) и private (закрытых) методов привязанного объекта.  доки читайте

Comment: [Вам про вот это говорят](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d63305e2e2e010fc3393f61a67bf79dd574e3373)   "Этот параметр определяет видимость protected (защищенных) и private (закрытых) методов привязанного объекта." - Это значит что, указав вторым параметром объект, вы даете доступ к его защищенным и закрытым методам, а не то что вы можете писать во втором параметре `private | protected | public`

Comment: @Naumov Я читал документацию я даже ссылку в своем вопросе приводил, но вы каким то необычайным образом ссылаете читать меня то что я уже читал...браво!

Comment: @Bookin В шапке вопроса я четко спрашивал, что есть неуказанная область видимости, но всем либо пофиг что я спрашиваю и толдычат мне иди мануал читай, что успешно делает товарищ Naumov, некоторые просто даже не отвечают, но считают своим долгом заминусить вопрос, замечательно

Comment: @MaximPro я к Naumov обращался, это относится только его ответу не более.

Comment: @Bookin ясно, просто вы не указали к кому обращаетесь, вот я и на вас тоже подумал

Comment: @Bookin Мда поправил ответ спасибо "сам видимо не дочитал" :D